# System font disappear on UIButton attributed title

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have an UIButton and I changed its title to `attributed`.

Now that the title is attributed I need to keep the font - "System font".

Unfortunately I can't find system font because when I made the UIButton title to attributed, I can't get this menu anymore:

[image: the good menu]

Instead I only get this menu:

[image: bad menu]

and here, in the larger menu, I can't find system font.

where is the system font in the menu or how can I add system font via interface builder when using UIButton attributed title?

Please don't suggest thing like "Adding a label with _______ under the UIButton" or "UIImageView with the text".

Comment: Family is system font only in that pic. scroll it, select your font, you will get typeface also as regular and all.

Answer (score 1):

From storyboard, changing attributed text back to system font can be frustrating.

#### Solution 1: redo it

Well, if the attributed text is simple enough, I could advise this:

1. switch it to plain text:
   [image: state configuration]
2. set the font back to system
3. switch it back to attributed text
4. re-apply the desired formatting

#### Solution 2: edit the XML

If the attributed string is complex, you may want to go carefully:

1. switch to the Version Editor (or open the storyboard with an external editor  like BBEdit or Sublime Text) to edit the XML source of the storyboard
   [image]
2. find the guilty font, like:

   ```
   <font key="NSFont" size="17" name="ComicSansMS"/>
   ```
3. replace with a meta font, like:

   ```
   <font key="NSFont" metaFont="system" size="17"/>
   ```
4. return to the Standard Editor

---

Note that I rarely use attributed strings from storyboard because it can't support translations. So in general, you'll use the storyboard with some *lorem ipsum*, and set the adequate NSAttributedString from code.

Answer (score 0):

The current iOS system font is "San Francisco"

You can use it via:

```
UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat, weight: UIFontWeight)
```

You can also download the fonts via a link on this page: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/typography/

Comment: SF mono? there is no "San Francisco"

Comment: Not sure what your question is... Are you looking for "SF Mono"? Or are you looking for the default iOS System Font?

Comment: You said "The current iOS system font is "San Francisco"" but there is no "San Francisco" font on the list. there is only "SF mono" - did you mean "SF mono" is the System font?

Comment: "San Francisco" is the "Name" of the font, but like many fonts, the Name is not necessarily what is displayed in a font list, nor is it what you use to identify the font if you've added it to your project. If you read the page I linked to, you would have seen that iOS uses `SF Pro Text for text 19 points or smaller, SF Pro Display for text 20 points or larger`. "SF Mono" is used by OSX for various things (such as Terminal) for **Mono-Spaced** fonts. So... do you *need* the Mono-Spaced version?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to do this without the storyboard.

Checkout this sample code:

```
class VC: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton! //button outlet

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Initialization code
        ///here we are defining the attributes for the button title...

        let textAttribute: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]

        self.button.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "Button", attributes: textAttribute), for: .selected)
    }
}
```